# why my javascript code doesnt behave as I expect

Tags: javascript

The `if` statement doesn't work, it goes to the else statement, even though the colors match

Can you please tell me where's the bug?

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(255,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,255)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(255,0,255)"
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    //add initial colors to squares
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

    // add click listeners to squares
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        //grab color of clicked squares
        var clickedColor = this.style.background;
        //compare color to pickedColor
        if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
            alert("correct");
        }
        else {
            alert("wrong");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: can you post your html as well

Comment: I've never seen basic language features like flow control structures not behaving properly. If it goes to the else statement it must be because the condition is false. Seriously. Why don't you `console.log()` both variables and see if for yourself?

Comment: can you update your code with full version

Comment: The best way to figure out things like this is to use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser. Open "dev tools" via the menu (or by using Ctrl+Shift+I [Cmd+Shift+I on Macs] or F12 on most browsers). You can set breakpoints, look at variable values, etc. In this case, you would have seen that `this.style.background` was coming back with a different string than the one you used to set it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: No need to stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, when you can *turn on the lights* with the debugger. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hey, that's a convincing metaphor indeed. I now feel guilty for even suggesting it... <:-)

Comment: thanks you two! I just figured out that it returned me rgb(0, 255, 255)  with spaces, which I didn't have in my code. So I just had to add, and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. Browsers don't necessarily give you back the color value in the notation you used to set it. For instance, you may well get back `rgba(255,0,0,0)` instead of `rgb(255,0,0)`.
2. You're using the `background` compound property, so the browser is probably giving you back more than just the background color (which would be `backgroundColor`).

Instead, store the color as a data attribute so you can compare strings without worrying about the representation the browser uses.

Also note that there's no reason to recreate the function on every loop; just use a single function for all the elements:

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(255,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,255)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(255,0,255)"
];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    //add initial colors to squares
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];       // ***
    squares[i].setAttribute("data-color", colors[i]);   // ***

    // add click listeners to squares
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", clickHandler); // ***
}
function clickHandler() {
    //grab color of clicked squares
    var clickedColor = this.getAttribute("data-color"); // ***
    //compare color to pickedColor
    if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
        alert("correct");
    }
    else {
        alert("wrong");
    }
}
```

---

Side note: The blocks connected to control structures don't have a `;` after them (though putting one there is harmless). But you do put a `;` after the initializer in a `var` (such as your initial colors array); leaving it off is relying on JavaScript's Automatic Semicolon Insertion error-correction mechanism.